# strange border at bottom of image

Tags: css, image, border

I can't seem to find out why some images at a project of mine (http://www.de-drie.nl) have a strange (grey?) border at the bottom. Could it be since the images aren't scaled? I have scaled them to fit content with css.

At first this problem was there in: FF, Chrome, IE and Safari. After playing a bit with the width (in css) of the images the strange border disappeared in FF.

The other browsers are still showing the border problem.

I have seen multiple posts here at stackoverflow which describe the same kind of problem.
The solution should be display:block or vertical-align:bottom, but this really doesn't seem to work for my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All your images with grey border in the html, literally the actual images contain a small grey border underneath

For example this: http://www.de-drie.nl/images/uitbouw.jpg contains this:

[image]

Comment: oh my god :/ (slapping myself hard). thanks a lot! p.s. what tool did you use in you're posted image (the magnifying glass)? Is it a firefox extension?

Comment: Actually its photoshop. I zoomed in, screenshot, pasted the screenshot in a circle form, in the actual image.